# Creating a scheduled action in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am writing something that will perform an action on a scheduled delay based on a user input.  I think I am close but it is not performing as I would expect it to.  I keep getting a negative result.  This is what I have so far:

```
    If SchedMsgBox = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
      Delay = "Y"
      CurTime = Now()
      DeployDt = Format(Me.cmbSchedDT.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
     '   MsgBox ("DeployDate: " & DeployDt)
      DeployTime = Format(Me.lstSchedTime.Value, "hh:mm AMPM")
     '   MsgBox ("DeployTime: " & DeployTime)
      DeployDateTime = DeployDt & " " & DeployTime
     '   MsgBox ("DeployDateTime: " & DeployDateTime)
     '   DelayTimeMin = DateDiff("n", CurTime, DeployDateTime)
      DelayTime = DateDiff("s", CurTime, DeployDateTime)
     '   MsgBox ("DelayTimeInSec: " & DelayTime)

    End If
```

Any Ideas what I have wrong?

*Delay Time being the final product of seconds that the procedure will be delayed. 
Deploytime and Deploy Date come from the User input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is that you get a negative value for `DelayTime` from this line ...

```vb
DelayTime = DateDiff("s", CurTime, DeployDateTime)
```

... that would be reasonable if `DeployDateTime` is earlier than `CurTime`.

Here is an Immediate window example ...

```vb
CurTime = Now()
? CurTime
12/16/2013 11:57:06 AM 
DeployDateTime = "2013-12-16 11:30"
? DateDiff("s", CurTime, DeployDateTime)
-1626
```

Although `DeployDateTime` is text rather than Date/Time datatype in my example and in your code, `DateDiff` cooperates by casting it to Date/Time when it computes the difference.  I don't see how that type difference would be creating a problem here.

Perhaps you just need to swap the order of the 2 time arguments.

```vb
? DateDiff("s", DeployDateTime, CurTime)
 1626
```

Comment: Hans - I think you are correct I have the order backwards.  But my other issue is that it appears that the result is still incorrect.  I Set my DeployDateTime(The first in the Datediff Func) to be 1 min ahead of the CurrTime and my result is 34800.

Comment: Confirm you're giving `DateDiff` the values you expect.  This expression returns 60: `DateDiff("s", "2013-12-16 11:29", "2013-12-16 11:30")`

Comment: I made a change Got rid of
    CurTime = Now()
And Just used Now() in the Datediff section That seemed to do the trick.  Not sure why but glad it works.... 
Thanks for your help, much appreciated!